# How can I get LWC Component to work. Error Invalid Descriptor Format: lightning-record-edit-form[COMPONENT]: Source

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
 Getting Error:
```

Invalid Descriptor Format: lightning-record-edit-form[COMPONENT]: Source

```
<aura:component controller="UpdateSpaController">

<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />  
<!--<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>-->

<aura:attribute name="WorkActivity" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="ScopeOfBidRegistration" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="BusinessReasonforBidRegistration" type="String" />
<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>
<aura:attribute name="Spinner" type="boolean" />


<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
    <template>
        <lightning-record-edit-form record-id="{!v.recordId}"
                                    object-api-name="Contact">
            <div class="slds-box">
                <lightning-input-field fieldName="Name" />
                <lightning-input-field fieldName="Account" />
                <lightning-input-field fieldName="MailingAddress" />
            </div>

        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </template>
   </div>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things wrong with your approach here. First of all: you are mixing Aura component tags with Lightning Web components tags. They can't be used together this way. LWC declare attributes on the `.js` file, not using tags on the `.html` file.

Second error I can identify in your edit form: Lightning web components do not use the value provider style of referencing attributes. Instead of `"{!v.recordId}"` you should use just `{recordId}`.

This code of yours will never compile and get saved on the server as it is.

I suggest taking a look into the [LWC documentation on how to create components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_introduction).

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I cannot do it in the developer console.

Comment: To add on to what Renato said, here is a link to documentation that irons out the differences between Aura component tags with Lightning Web components tags. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_map_aura_lwc_components